# How can I trim everything between certain characters in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am using a select query to get the email Ids. However in email ID column except email there is a text in between `;` and `:` which I want to trim so that I can only get the email Ids nothing else.

For example:-

`;some text here: abc.def@xyz.com` ---- this is the data, and I want to select only email ID not the text before that.

How can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the unwanted text would always appear *before* the email address, then you need only use substring:

```sql
SELECT col, TRIM(SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ':') + 1)) AS email
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo